# Calculating the area of an irregular semi-circle

Tags: area, volume

I am very inexperienced when it comes to math and I'd like to calculate the area of an irregular semi circle. This shape is 200 ft wide and an average of 20 feet deep. (Like a wide trough shape). Any help with this will be greatly appreciated!

[Example diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EHCyG.png)

Many thanks!

Comment: by irregular semicircle what do you mean? would be good if you could include a  diagram

Comment: @tjm118 are you talking of shape like a crater

Comment: I added a rudimentary diagram

Comment: It seems like you are talking about a section of a circle (or perhaps an ellipse) cut off by a line.  What do you mean by "an average of 20 ft deep?"  What is the maximum depth in you picture?  (It seems to me that any figure which is 200 ft wide and an average of 20 ft deep has an area of 4,000 sq. ft., since I would define the average depth as the area divided by the width.)

Comment: Maybe you are referring to a segment of a circle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you are thinking about ellipses. They have a formula for the area.

This is an ellipse:

[image: Ellipse]

Note that it doesn't have a radius, but two "axis".

The area of a circle is $\pi\cdot r^2$, with $r$ the radius. The area of an ellipse if $\pi\cdot A\cdot B$, which is a nice generalization.

The drawing you made could be half an ellipse, so you have to divide the area by a factor of $2$.

Do you want to know why the formula is like that?

Comment: Thank you Guillermo. I assume then that to calculate the area of half that shape I would take (pi * A * B) / 2

Comment: Exactly! But in your drawing you only have the value of one axis, and the length of the curve. You have to get the length of the other axis first :-)